# Dnn 8: caching module settings

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke

I put some module settings via

```
var moduleController = new ModuleController();
moduleController.UpdateModuleSetting(moduleId, "key", value);
```

Later if I try to access the setting using

```
var rcModule = ModuleController.Instance.GetModuleByDefinition(PortalSettings.PortalId, "MyModule");
var value = rcModule.ModuleSettings["value"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

the same value is returned (even if I resave the setting) until I clear the app cache. The value is correct after every saving settings in the database but not in the module. I also tried to add `ModuleController.SynchronizeModule(moduleId);` to my save settings method but it didn't help. Module and page cache both disabled.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `moduleController`, not getting the existing one from memory.

You can clear the cache programmatically.

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearModuleCache(TabId);
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearTabsCache(PortalId);
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearPortalCache(PortalId, false);
```

Or get the correct instance and edit the properties.

```
ModuleInfo moduleInfo = ModuleController.Instance.GetModule(ModuleId, TabId, false);
moduleInfo.ModuleTitle = "New Title";
ModuleController.Instance.UpdateModule(moduleInfo);
```